# tensorflow Found more than one graph event per run

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am loading a tensorboard for my ml engine experiment that is running in local mode and got the following warning:

```
"Found more than one graph event per run, or there was a metagraph containing a graph_def, as well as one or more graph events.  Overwriting the graph with the newest event.
W0825 19:26:12.435613 Reloader event_accumulator.py:311] Found more than one metagraph event per run. Overwriting the metagraph with the newest event."
```

Originally, I suspected that this was because I had not cleared my `--logdir=$OUTPUT_PATH` (as other posts suggested -- however, even if I performed `rm -rf $OUTPUT_PATH/*` I am still getting this error for a local train. Could this error be indicative of a larger issue in my graph?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you may have already come across [this post](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9512), but without more information, it's the best information I can provide:

> This is a known issue, TensorBoard doesn't like it when you write
>   multiple event files from separate runs in the same directory. It will
>   be fixed if you use a new subdirectory for every run (new
>   hyperparameters = new subdirectory).

You may be inadvertently writing multiple event files in the same directory (e.g. training and eval?).

Also, be sure you are returning an appropriate `tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec` when in `modes.EVAL`. From the [census sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/84cf80d0c744a7072ebd5632f87de649a4630ce9/census/customestimator/trainer/model.py#L220):

```
if mode == Modes.EVAL:
  labels_one_hot = tf.one_hot(
      label_indices_vector,
      depth=label_values.shape[0],
      on_value=True,
      off_value=False,
      dtype=tf.bool
  )
  eval_metric_ops = {
      'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(label_indices, predicted_indices),
      'auroc': tf.metrics.auc(labels_one_hot, probabilities)
  }
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

Comment: I think that is certainly possible. I am writing scalars in both Modes.EVAL and Modes.TRAIN and the scalars in Modes.EVAL are never showing up in tensorboard. I guess I thought that there were always two event files (eval/event and train/event) but I'm now thinking that it's not quite as simple.  Is there a way to write scalars for both train/eval within the same model_fn so that they don't generate multiple event files in the same directory?

Comment: What are you setting as your model_dir (e.g. run_config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(model_dir=args.job_dir))? Can you provide a directory listing of that model_dir?

Comment: Updated the post with info about EstimatorSpec. Does that help?

Comment: It's evident that I must be writing multiple event files, but I'm not exactly sure how this is happening. I am deleting the args.job_dir every time with 'rm -rf $JOB_DIR' and then I am still ending up with this error once I start a new run.  Here is the directory listing of that model_dir.. `$ ls output
checkpoint
events.out.tfevents.1504204297.Users-MacBook-Pro.local
graph.pbtxt
model.ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-1.index
model.ckpt-1.meta` and as far as I can tell there is only the single events file, but the tensorboard warning is still yelling at me?

Comment: There is however now another subdirectory `eval` which does contain another events file, but the warning was showing up before that was even the case..

Comment: Now that the eval is there, are things working correctly? If you don't explicitly set model_dir, I wonder if the summaries are going to some default dir which you aren't cleaning out all the time.

Comment: I did specify run_config as you described `tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(model_dir=args.job_dir` -- Now that eval is there I got some additional warnings: `WARNING:tensorflow:Deleting accumulator 'eval'
WARNING:tensorflow:Deleting accumulator '.'
WARNING:tensorflow:Found more than one graph event per run, or there was a metagraph containing a graph_def, as well as one or more graph events.  Overwriting the graph with the newest event.
WARNING:tensorflow:Found more than one metagraph event per run. Overwriting the metagraph with the newest event.`