# MonitoredTrainingSession writes more than one metagraph event per run

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

When writing checkpoint files using a `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` it somehow writes multiple metagraphs. What am I doing wrong?

I stripped it down to the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
global_step = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False, name="global_step")
train = tf.assign(global_step, global_step + 1)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
hooks = [(tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook(checkpoint_dir=output_path + "test1/ckpt/",
                                          save_steps = 10,
                                          saver = saver))]

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master = '',
                                       is_chief = True,
                                       checkpoint_dir = None,
                                       hooks = hooks,
                                       save_checkpoint_secs = None,
                                       save_summaries_steps = None,
                                       save_summaries_secs = None) as mon_sess:
    for i in range(30):
        if mon_sess.should_stop():
            break
        try:
            gs, _ = mon_sess.run([global_step, train])
            print(gs)
        except (tf.errors.OutOfRangeError,tf.errors.CancelledError) as e:
            break
        finally:
            pass
```

Running this will give duplicate metagraphs, as evidenced by the tensorboard warning:

```
$ tensorboard --logdir ../train/test1/ --port=6006
```

> WARNING:tensorflow:Found more than one graph event per run, or there
>   was a metagraph containing a graph_def, as well as one or more graph
>   events.  Overwriting the graph with the newest event. Starting
>   TensorBoard 54 at local:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

This is in tensorflow **1.2.0** (I cannot upgrade).

Running the same thing without a monitored session gives the right checkpoint output:

```
global_step = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False, name="global_step")
train = tf.assign(global_step, global_step + 1)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    for i in range(30):
        gs, _ = sess.run([global_step, train])
        print(gs)
        if i%10==0:
            saver.save(sess, output_path+'/test2/my-model', global_step=gs)
            print("Saved ckpt")
```

Results in no tensorboard errors:

```
$ tensorboard --logdir ../traitest2/ --port=6006
```

> Starting TensorBoard 54 at local:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

I'd like to fix this as I suspect I'm missing something fundamental, and this error may have some connection to other issues I have in distributed mode. I have to restart tensorboard anytime I want to update the data. Moreover, TensorBoard seems to get really slow over time when it puts out many of these warnings.

There is a related question: [tensorflow Found more than one graph event per run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890560/tensorflow-found-more-than-one-graph-event-per-run)
In this case the errors were due to multiple runs (with different parameters) written to the same output directory. The case here is about a single run to a clean output directory.

Running the MonitoredTrainingSession version in distributed mode gives the same errors.

**Update Oct-12**

@Nikhil Kothari suggested to use `tf.train.MonitoredSession` instead of the larger `tf.train.MonitoredTrainSession` wrapper, as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
global_step = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False, name="global_step")
train = tf.assign(global_step, global_step + 1)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
hooks[(tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook(checkpoint_dir=output_path + "test3/ckpt/",
                                            save_steps=10,
                                            saver=saver))]

chiefsession = tf.train.ChiefSessionCreator(scaffold=None,
                                            master='',
                                            config=None,
                                            checkpoint_dir=None,
                                            checkpoint_filename_with_path=None)
with tf.train.MonitoredSession(session_creator=chiefsession,
                hooks=hooks,
                stop_grace_period_secs=120) as mon_sess:
    for i in range(30):
        if mon_sess.should_stop():
            break
        try:
            gs, _ = mon_sess.run([global_step, train])
            print(gs)
        except (tf.errors.OutOfRangeError,tf.errors.CancelledError) as e:
            break
        finally:
            pass
```

Unfortunately this still gives the same tensorboard errors:

```
$ tensorboard --logdir ../train/test3/ --port=6006
```

> WARNING:tensorflow:Found more than one graph event per run, or there
>   was a metagraph containing a graph_def, as well as one or more graph
>   events.  Overwriting the graph with the newest event. Starting
>   TensorBoard 54 at local:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

btw, each codeblock is stand-alone, copy=paste it in a Jupyter notebook and you will replicate the problem.

Comment: I'm sure you aware of this but just in case...
If you specify `checkpoint_dir = your_path` when creating the `MonitoredTrainingSession` it will just work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it just now, to add the checkpoint_dir in both the MonitoredSession and the hook. No difference though. It "works just fine", kinda fine,.. still have the issue of multiple graph events though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if this is because every node in your cluster is running the same code, declaring itself as a chief, and saving out graphs and checkpoints.

I don't if the is_chief = True is just illustrative in the post here on Stack Overflow or that is exactly what you are using... so guessing a bit here.

I personally used MonitoredSession instead of MonitoredTrainingSession and created a list of hooks based on whether the code is running on the master/chief or not. Example: https://github.com/TensorLab/tensorfx/blob/master/src/training/_trainer.py#L94

Comment: The code above replicates the problem in single thread, yes ultimately I want to work in distributed but this question is about just getting it right in the simple case. I'll take a look at MonitoredSession, do you know what the difference is, conceptionally?

Comment: MonitoredTrainingSession adds various hooks based on is_chief vs. not ... but in my case, I just wanted full control + use my own hook implementations, so I didn't use the derived class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried `MonitoredSession` but it gives the same errors still. I updated the question with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the parameter **chief_only_hooks** in 'MonitoredTrainingSession', the code as follows:

```
hooks = [(tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook(checkpoint_dir=output_path + "test1/ckpt/",
                                      save_steps = 10,
                                      saver = saver))]

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master = '',
                                   is_chief = True,
                                   checkpoint_dir = None,
                                   chief_only_hooks = hooks,
                                   save_checkpoint_secs = None,
                                   save_summaries_steps = None,
                                   save_summaries_secs = None) as mon_sess:
```